# How to create a test apk from an Android aar file?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

The [Android Gradle documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Differences-between-a-Project-and-a-Library-Project) says this:

> A library project can also generate a test apk to test the library  independently from an application.

But I don't find a way to do that. The `assembleDebug`/`assembleRelease` targets don't seem to generate any APK.

How do I get an APK from a (standalone) library?

Comment: Good question. I'm asking myself what that APK should contain, since a library does not make an application...

Answer (score 1):

You can add assembleDebugTest build task for generating test apk from library project.
This test apk can be used to test the library as it contains both the test code along with the library code.